# Review my F# QuickSort Program

Tags: functional-programming, sorting, f#, quick-sort

OK... last sort of the day and probably the most fun. F# is really awesome.

```
let rec quickSort list = 
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [x]
    | hd :: _ -> 
        quickSort (List.filter (fun x -> x < hd) list) @ hd :: quickSort (List.filter (fun x -> x > hd) list)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    printfn "%s" (List.fold (fun acc x -> acc + " " + x.ToString()) "" (quickSort [10; 7; 1; 0; -1; 9; 33; 12; 6; 2; 3; 33; 34;]))
    0
```

let me know How I can improve this code. I am trying to think functionally and want my program to be most efficient, concise and functional.

Comment: This will probably drop any duplicate elements as `x !< hd` and `x !> hd`

Comment: I do have a question though. since I make 2 calls to quickSort in the recursion... will these two calls be made parallelly? 

I have heard that functional languages are more multi-core friendly... but want to confirm if I have to do some thing explicilty to ensure that all the two sub quickSorts are executed on different threads.

Comment: The calls will not run on separate threads.  This is good as you could generate a lot of threads if itndid

Comment: OK... but they say that functional languages are more multi-core friendly as compared to imperative ones. so in the program above is there any multi-core benefit which I would not get in a traditional langugae.... also is there something I can do to be more multicore aware?

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch Multi-core-frienly means that they are easy to parallelize. But easy doesn't mean mean it's done automatlically.

Comment: Fair enough. So how do I parallelize the code above. I am very sure that the subcalls to 2 methods can execute on their own threads.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch You can use normal .Net `Task`s for that. Something like `Task.Run(fun () -> quickSort ...)` to start two `Task`s and then call `Result` on both of them to get the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd:

- exclude unnecessary duplication (`List.filter` etc.)
- drop separate match rule for the list of one element
- rely on type inference
- use more succinct form of pattern matching

Something like this:

```
let rec qsort = function
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> let lt, ge = List.partition ((>) x) xs
               qsort lt @ x :: qsort ge
```